# Authentication failed on GitHub

Tags: git, github, git-push

Entering correct password but still getting error.
Can someone pls tell me if there is a technical error or am I doing it in a wrong way?

[image: Error message]

Comment: see the error message, this way of authentication is not supported anymore. You need to go to the URL in the message and follow the instructions there

Comment: Paste console output **as text** in future!!! And read suggested in message document at least

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgithub%5D+Support+for+password+authentication+was+removed.+Please+use+a+personal+access+token+instead.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use token authentication. [Check this](https://www.theserverside.com/blog/Coffee-Talk-Java-News-Stories-and-Opinions/How-to-create-a-GitHub-Personal-Access-Token-example)